# js works in codepen but not local files

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to close a modal by clicking outside of it. It is working fine within a pen on codepen, but not within a codepen project or local files. What am I missing?

The header code in my HTML file is:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
```

Not sure if importing jQuery is necessary, but most answers on this topic that I read here instructed to add it. Results are the same with or without it.

And the entirety of my js file is just:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I've also tried putting the js directly in the script tags in the HTML file, which is also not running.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here's the full code: https://codepen.io/phoenixparker/pen/KKVExJG

Comment: Add scripts before end of the body tag instead of head tag.

Comment: not working locally? then check console for errors

Comment: console shows no errors, and changing whether the script is in the body or head makes no difference

Comment: Probably `modal` is `null` because you call `document.getElementById('id01')` in a place in your HTML file before the actual `<div id="id01">` element, so it doesn't exist yet when you try to reference it. Are you sure you put it at the _end_ of the body, not the start? Please set a breakpoint in the `onclick` function and step through the code and check the values of `modal` and `event.target` to see what's going on. Actually it feels to me as if you'd need the opposite - `if (event.target !== modal)` - plus, what if the user clicks somewhere inside of the modal on a child element?

Comment: Putting it at the bottom of the body tag worked! Thanks so much! I'm not sure how to mark this as answered since this was a comment and not an answer though.

Comment: or add defer to script  tag

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work here too, you code it right. Maybe you misstyped the id?

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="id01">here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check where is your `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`file is located. You might have this file not in the same directory as the page you are opening, so it cannot load it. Press Ctrl+Shift+I in google chrome and check Console for any errors. Check your script location as releative to the page you are opening.

Comment: It's in the same directory, but I've also tested putting it in its own directory and changing the path to /js/script.js or ./js/script.js. Not getting any errors from the console.

Comment: Then you should start doing step by step debugging:
1) Assign simple event like console.write or window.alert with any word on the click event
Here you can check if you catch the click event
2) Then start adding your code with small steps, like getting, storing and displaying data, then you will find where your problem is.